How do I bring across the background colour with the text from a drop-down list?
I have an Excel 365 workbook with 2 tabs – Lists and Detail. On the Lists tab I have a list of Responsible Parties like this

Users are able to add more items by inserting above the N/A cell and they can change the background colour and/or text of any of the cells to meet their specific requirements.
On the Detail tab, various cells (almost 100 so far) use the list via a drop-down, i.e. they can only select an item from the list.

My question is this: How do I bring across the background colour from the list along with the text?
I’ve tried Conditional Formatting, which works only until the user changes the background colour (or text) of one or more item/s in the List, or inserts additional items in the List, each with its own background colour.
On the face of it, this sounds simple, but I’ve searched extensively, without finding an elegant solution, so any help/pointers will be welcome.

Use the worksheet_change event to detect a change/addition in the column with the drop-downs, then use the new value to match against the source list and copy the fill color from the matched cell

Use Worksheet_Change event on sheet Detail.
Right click on sheet tab > View Code > Insert code as below
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim oDic As Object
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Sheets("Lists").Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' modify as needed
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then oDic(c.Value) = c.Interior.Color
    Next
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            If oDic.exists(c.Value) Then
                c.Interior.Color = oDic(c.Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Assuming the list on the sheet Lists

Output on the sheet Detail


Update: (Thanks for @Tim's comment)

As they can change the background colour and/or text of any of the cells to meet their specific requirements, Worksheet_Activate event code is added to refresh filling color on sheet Detail.

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1)) ' modify as needed
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Call UpdateColor
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call UpdateColor
End Sub

Sub UpdateColor()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    With Sheets("Detail")
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1))  ' modify as needed
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim oDic As Object
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Sheets("Lists").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        oDic(c.Value) = c.Interior.Color
    Next
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            If oDic.exists(c.Value) Then
                c.Interior.Color = oDic(c.Value)
            Else ' remove filling if not exist in Lists, modify as needed
                ' c.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub



For the OP: since it was noted that users can change the background color on the "Lists" sheet, it might be worth adding a worksheet_activate event handler on "Detail", to re-sync the colors in case of changes.

@TimWilliams It's a good point. Thanks. I'll update the scrpt later.

Use conditional formatting to color-code the drop-down list:
Select the cells with the drop-down list
Click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule
Select Format only cells that contain
Choose the condition for color
Select the color formatting
Click Format
Activate the Fill tab
Select the highlight color
Click OK, then click OK again

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
